# Why is precision so low despite setting working precision to 25?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

I am currently generating some Gauss-Jacobi quadrature rules. Along the way, I have to find zeroes of Jacobi polynomials. In particular, I have this piece of code:

```
n = 20;
lambda = -0.91103252643507214171824629081;
roots = Values @@@ Solve[JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*x - 1] == 0, x, WorkingPrecision -> 25];
```

I am generating quadrature rules of various size n, and copying the results into my C++ code. I require at least double precision, however I set working precision to 25 to be safe. For small n, this is fine and I get results like this (here n=5):

```
{0.0036430793106229828861591, 0.148747571389169588280654, 0.425033440432816690797753, 0.728008911489383545849755, 0.943979532661912865533522}
```

However, for large n, the results are clearly not of high precision (here n=25):

```
{0.000148053, 0.006350865, 0.020340493, 0.04186708, 0.07059090, 0.1060603, 0.1477178, 0.1949087, 0.246891, 0.302849, 0.361902, 0.42312, 0.48555, 0.54820, 0.6101, 0.6702, 0.7277, 0.7816, 0.8311, 0.875, 0.914, 0.946, 0.970, 0.988, 0.9977}
```

This is a massive issue, as my quadrature rules will have errors far too large for my liking. How can I maintain high precision for large n?

Comment: There is a warning in the documentation for `JacobiP`: "Cancellations in the polynomial form may lead to inaccurate numerical results" -- If I have time, I'll try to look up a better approach. I'm pretty sure there is one, but I don't know the details.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Okay, that is interesting, and a bit scary. If the roots are a bit off, my quadrature rules will also be off, and my entire scheme (I am working on a numerical scheme for a PDE with singularity) will be only as good as the quadratures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 20;
lambda = SetAccuracy[-0.91103252643507214171824629081, Infinity];
roots = Values @@@ 
  Solve[JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*x - 1] == 0, x, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
n = 20;
lambda = -0.91103252643507214171824629081;
roots = Values @@@ 
  Solve[JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*x - 1] == 0, x, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

There is a warning in the documentation for JacobiP: "Cancellations in the polynomial form may lead to inaccurate numerical results"

One way to prevent the polynomial form is to use `?NumericQ` and `FindRoot`. Here we can use `FindRoot` to polish the roots from `Solve`:

```
n = 20;
lambda = -0.91103252643507214171824629081;
roots = Values @@@ 
   Solve[JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*x - 1] == 0, x, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 25];
obj[x_?NumericQ, n_Integer] := JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*x - 1];
froots = 
 x /. FindRoot[obj[x, n], {x, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 25] & /@ roots
```

A different approach is a matrix-eigenvalue approach. Orthogonal polynomials can be represented as scalar multiple of the characteristic polynomial of a so-called "comrade matrix."  There is already a resource function that calculates the comrade matrix of many orthogonal polynomials.

```
cm = ResourceFunction["ComradeMatrix"]; 
cmroots = Rescale[
 Sort@ Eigenvalues@
    cm[UnitVector[n + 1, n + 1], {JacobiP, 0, lambda}],
 {-1, 1}, {0, 1}]
```

Check:

```
cmroots - froots // Abs // Max
(*  6.8*10^-24  *)

JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*cmroots - 1] // Abs // Max
(*  0.*10^-25  *)

JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*froots - 1] // Abs // Max
(*  3.4*10^-22  *)
```

FWIW, the eigenvalue-comrade-matrix method seems slightly more accurate than `FindRoot` in this case.

For $n \ge 100$, there's this 2013 paper by Hale and Townsend, https://doi.org/10.1137/120889873 ([pdf](https://www.chebfun.org/publications/HaleTownsend2013a.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

Try these

```
n = 20;
lambda = -0.91103252643507214171824629081 // Rationalize[#, 1] &;
roots = Values @@@ Solve[JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*x - 1] == 0, x] // N[#, 25] &
```

or maybe

```
n = 20;
lambda = -0.91103252643507214171824629081`40;
roots = Values @@@ Solve[JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2*x - 1] == 0, x]
```

Evidently precision is lost during the calculation, so you need to start with higher precision than 25 to get the end result you want.

Answer (score 2):

Why not work with exact values, and numericize later?

```
n = 20;
lambda = Rationalize[-0.91103252643507214171824629081, 0];
roots = Values @@@ Solve[JacobiP[n, 0, lambda, 2 x - 1] == 0, x];
```

The output of roots is rather large, so I didn't include it. Then you can numericize roots to any desired precision:

```
N[roots, 30]
```

> {0.000231117845840521143282918337671, 0.00990249022459434098996291996350, 
> 0.0316317783340785337674994343999, 0.0648394050341808826989667806444, 
> 0.108709031724208147595639186528, 0.162164802095006116349812863730, 
> 0.223896158082531780493670206159, 0.292389747439738852985614488065, 
> 0.365966472097961730188410157436, 0.442822634912143019385414656019, 
> 0.521074150701053889527939956484, 0.598802731380168793212124614807, 
> 0.674102911139798300352767233972, 0.745128758536103342507931561266, 
> 0.810139131091171971961795668374, 0.867540365884237868735793634041, 
> 0.915925370143497153121659679362, 0.954108201108410534415525936595, 
> 0.981153596187887421540250594744, 0.996404737452615437594298910661}

Comment: Okay, that is interesting. I was under the impression Solve had a default precision.